# elmah: exceptions without HttpContext?

Tags: c#, asp.net, exception, elmah, httpcontext

I spawn a thread on Application_Start and would like to log exceptions. There is no `Context/HttpContext/HttpContext.Current`, so how might I get it to log?

At the moment, it does not catch any exception in my threads and if I write `ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);` I get an error about context cannot be null.

Maybe I can create a dummy HttpContext but somehow I don't think that will work well.

**-edit-** I tried `ErrorSignal.Get(new HttpApplication()).Raise(ex);` and it doesn't seem to pick up that exception.

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Make sure you set your application name in web.config

```
<errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" 
          connectionStringName="nibWeb" 
          applicationName="Nib.Services" />
```

and then

```
ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(error));
```

will work

Comment: For what it's worth, if you're using Elmah's in-memory logging, you don't need to make the configuration change, just call ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(error));

Comment: WARNING: this approach does NOT seem to raise a true Elmah Error event -- for instance, you will not receive an error email (if you have that configured). You need to call .Raise() for that. Unfortunately, you need to have an HttpContext for .Raise(), so the only way I know to do that in these sort of situations is to store a HttpContext and use it later.

Answer (score 2):

I wasn't using `<errorLog>` as in Brendan Carey's answer because I was only in-memory logging.  Nevertheless, his command worked great in my case without naming the application:

```
Elmah.ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Elmah.Error(new Exception("The application has done something.")));
```

I DID have to recompile Elmah with .NET 4.0, because of an error about needing System.Web.Abstractions 3.5.0.0.  My compiled-for-.NET 4.0 fork is here if anyone wants it (also strong naming):

http://code.google.com/r/scottstafford-elmah/

Comment: NOTE: Once I switched to using sql logging, I did need ApplicationName.

Answer (score 1):

For my application, I saved `this.Context.ApplicationInstance` in `Application_Start` so that I can call `Elmah.ErrorSignal.Get` with the saved instance. With the `ErrorSignal`, I could then `Raise`. This goes through all the email filters.

Below is the code. I use FluentScheduler to

```
public class Global : HttpApplication {
    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {

        var application = Context.ApplicationInstance;
        FluentScheduler.TaskManager.UnobservedTaskException +=
            (FluentScheduler.Model.TaskExceptionInformation i, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs a) =>
                Elmah.ErrorSignal.Get(application).Raise(i.Task.Exception);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a solution to: [Using ELMAH in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841451/using-elmah-in-a-console-application) that adds ability to send email, tweets and filter in addition to logging.