# Error handling in MVC using ELMAH

Tags: c#, error-handling, asp.net-mvc-4, elmah.mvc

I've been playing around with ELMAH in my MVC4 application. I've downloaded ELMAH from Nuget and it sets the configuration for me. I know that ELMAH for MVC will catch errors in controllers, but how about errors else where? For instance error inside Application_Start? I've managed to [log errors with ELMAH in the Application_Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108404/elmah-exceptions-without-httpcontext) but unable to redirect it to MVC 4 error page in the /Shared/ folder. Is even this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes - for a local environment, the redirect won't work unless you have the web.config set to customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="Error"  and then you need to disable the global filter HandleError.  Comment out the HandleErrorAttribute line in RegisterGlobalFilters.

```
public static void RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilterCollection filters)
{
    //filters.Add(new HandleErrorAttribute());
}
```

Comment: Why do we need to disable the HandleErrorAttribute?

Comment: Because you are handling errors through Elmah in Application_Error.

Comment: If you comment out that line then, you want to show a custom error page. How will you do it?. It's not a good solution. You should create a new custom error filter and add that to filters then you can comment out this.

Comment: Elmah already had a handler that doesn't need to be registered.  You can leave it in, but you'll be getting duplicate entries in ELMAH.