# ELMAH in MVC 4 app, not working in Global.asax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, error-handling, global-asax, elmah

I have an MVC 4 web application. Using ELMAH, and Elmah.Contrib.WebApi, any exceptions that occur within my controllers, or API controllers (or their underlying services) are logged perfectly.

Where I run into trouble is with manually logging of errors. Specifically, inside my Global.asax, I have lots of initialization code (setting up automapper and the like). In order to catch problems which might happen in the initialization code, I have the following:

```
 protected void Application_Start()
    {
        try
        {
            ControllerBuilder.Current.SetControllerFactory(new ErrorHandlingControllerFactory());
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.IncludeErrorDetailPolicy = IncludeErrorDetailPolicy.Always;
            GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Filters.Add(new ElmahHandleErrorApiAttribute());

            AutoMapperConfiguration.Configure();
            AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

            WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
            FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
            RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
            BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
            AuthConfig.RegisterAuth();

            DatabaseConfig.Initialize();
            SecurityConfig.Initialize();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            var context = HttpContext.Current;
            var signal = ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);
            if (signal != null)
            {
                signal.Raise(e, context);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any exception caught inside the "catch" block will never be logged by ELMAH. Yet, I know that ELMAH is working because any other exceptions that will occur from this point on, inside any controller, will be logged. Therefore I have ruled out problems in the web.config, and the like.

Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When the Applicaiton is executing the code in `Application_Start` it is still being initialized, and it is not handling any HttpRequest.

So the problem with your code is that `HttpContext` is null. In fact, the line ´ErrorSignal.FromContext(context);´ will throw an `ArgumentNullException`.

However, you can still use Elmah when there is no HttpContext (and it will basically log the error message and stack trace) as explained in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2108404/elmah-exceptions-without-httpcontext).

So your catch would be:

```
catch (Exception e)
{
    ErrorLog.GetDefault(null).Log(new Error(e));
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Ok, that makes a ton of sense. Thanks! It does log to SQL now (which is my logging store) but the error does not appear in the ELMAH web log. I think the reason is that when I look in SQL, the "application" is blank, which must be related to the application still being initialized, as you said. But at least I have the error in SQL, which is far better than what I had, which is nothing. During my hours of troubleshooting, I had tried using the syntax above, but I later reverted it because I did not see the error on the error page, and I did not think to look in SQL. Thanks again!

Comment: Adding an applicationName attribute to the errorLog node in Web.config solved that problem. Now the error is logged in SQL and I see it in the error summary page. Perfect! Thank you.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Have you tried setting the application name in the web.config? See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2196594/1836935)

Comment: Posted my comment at the same time than you, I see you have already updated the web.config :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm a newbie to Elmah but have had luck with something like this:

```
catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);
            return Json(string.Format("Failure: {0}", ex.Message), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
```