# Configuring ELMAH with SQL Server logging with encrypted connection string

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql-server, iis, elmah

I'm attempting to configure ELMAH error logging in an ASP.NET 4 application using SQL Server 2008 R2. Is there any way I can tell ELMAH to call our in-house decryption function on the connection string we provide it? Do I need to modify the ELMAH source and rebuild?

```xml
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="elmah">
    <section name="security" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.SecuritySectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorLog" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorLogSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorMail" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorMailSectionHandler, Elmah" />
    <section name="errorFilter" requirePermission="false" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterSectionHandler, Elmah" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>

<elmah>
  <security allowRemoteAccess="1" />
  <errorLog type="Elmah.SqlErrorLog, Elmah" connectionStringName="ELMAH" />
</elmah>

<connectionStrings>
  <add name="ELMAH" connectionString="EncryptedConnectionString" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>

<system.webServer>
  <handlers>
    <add name="Elmah" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
  </handlers>
  <modules>
    <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
  </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can't just tell ELMAH to do something with your connection string. What you can do, however, is tell ELMAH to call you back when it needs an `ErrorLog`, giving you more control at run-time. You can then read the encrypted connection string, decrypt it with your in-house function and return an SqlErrorLog initialized with it.

To do this, you need to provide a method that is compatible with 
the [`ServiceProviderQueryHandler`](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/tags/REL-1.2/src/Elmah/ServiceCenter.cs#34) delegate. Here's the definition:

```
public delegate IServiceProvider ServiceProviderQueryHandler(object context);
```

The implementation of the method must return an instance of an object that implements `IServiceProvider`. If you don't feel like writing one yourself to start with, you can get one for free from the .NET Framework. See [`System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer`](http://www.google.com/url?sa=D&q=http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.design.servicecontainer.aspx). The service provider's `GetService` must respond to requests for the `ErrorLog` type and you can then, for example, return a `SqlErrorLog` object that has been initialized with a connection string manipulated at runtime. Here's a possible implementation:

```cs
var parent = ServiceCenter.Current;
ServiceCenter.Current = context => { 
    var container = new ServiceContainer(parent(context)); 
    var connectionSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["FOOBAR"];
    var connectionString = Decrypt(connectionSettings.ConnectionString);
    var log = new SqlErrorLog(connectionString); 
    container.AddService(typeof(ErrorLog), log); 
    return container; 
  } ;
```

This captures the current service point and installs your own instead. The lambda/delegate created pass on service requests to the captured service point when it cannot 
satisfy it directly, thus creating a chain. You tell ELMAH about your implementation by setting `ServiceCenter.Current` somewhere during the initialization of your application so that's where the above code will need to sit.

Bear in mind that this is a very simple implementation but it should be good enough to get you started and optimize later if needed.

Prior to this [addition in 1.2](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/issues/detail?id=149), the only way to do something similar required subclassing and other gymnastics and still yielded partial results. Now you just need to implement a method and hand it over to ELMAH and which simply responds to queries from ELMAH for objects based on their service type.

Answer (score 3):

As an addition to the post of Atif Aziz, here the VB.NET version (InitializeElmah_VB9 for the .NET 2.0 version [without lamdda], InitializeElmah for VB.NET for .NET 4.0)

```vb
Imports System.Web.SessionState

Public Class Global_asax
    Inherits System.Web.HttpApplication


    Public Overrides Sub Init()
        MyBase.Init()

        InitializeElmah_VB9()
        'InitializeElmah()'
    End Sub

    Public parent As Elmah.ServiceProviderQueryHandler = Nothing

    Sub InitializeElmah_VB9()
        ' TODO: Create Table + Functions '
        parent = Elmah.ServiceCenter.Current
        Elmah.ServiceCenter.Current = AddressOf ElmahCallback
    End Sub

    Function ElmahCallback(objContext As Object) As System.IServiceProvider
        Dim container As New System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer(parent(objContext))
        Dim connectionSettings As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("FOOBAR")

        Dim strConnectionString As String = connectionSettings.ConnectionString

        Dim x As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(strConnectionString)
        x.Password = CryptStrings.DeCrypt(x.Password)

        strConnectionString = x.ConnectionString

        Dim log As Elmah.SqlErrorLog = New Elmah.SqlErrorLog(strConnectionString)
        container.AddService(GetType(Elmah.ErrorLog), log)
        Return container
    End Function

    Sub InitializeElmah()
        ' TODO: Create Table + Functions '
        Dim parent As Elmah.ServiceProviderQueryHandler = Elmah.ServiceCenter.Current
        Elmah.ServiceCenter.Current = Function(context)
              Dim container As New System.ComponentModel.Design.ServiceContainer(parent(context))
              Dim connectionSettings As System.Configuration.ConnectionStringSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Foobar")
              Dim connectionString As String = connectionSettings.ConnectionString

              Dim x As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionStringBuilder(connectionString)

              x.Password = CryptStrings.DeCrypt(x.Password)

              connectionString = x.ConnectionString

              Dim log As Elmah.SqlErrorLog = New Elmah.SqlErrorLog(connectionString)
              container.AddService(GetType(Elmah.ErrorLog), log)

              Return container
          End Function

    End Sub


    Sub Application_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird beim Starten der Anwendung ausgelöst
    End Sub


    Sub Session_Start(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird beim Starten der Sitzung ausgelöst
    End Sub


    Sub Application_BeginRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird zu Beginn jeder Anforderung ausgelöst
    End Sub


    Sub Application_AuthenticateRequest(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird beim Versuch der Benutzerauthentifizierung ausgelöst
    End Sub


    Sub Application_Error(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird bei einem Fehler ausgelöst
    End Sub


    Sub Session_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird beim Beenden der Sitzung ausgelöst
    End Sub


    Sub Application_End(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
        ' Wird beim Beenden der Anwendung ausgelöst
    End Sub


End Class
```