# How do I append the SQL ELMAH_Error.ErrorID to the ELMAH Error Email Subject?

Tags: c#, asp.net, event-handling, httpmodule, elmah

I'm using ELMAH to log errors to a SQL database AND send an email. I'd like to append the ELMAH_Error.ErrorId to the subject of the ELMAH email.

I'm saving the ErrorId ELMAH provides in the ElmahLog_Logged event into a session variable as I discovered in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7895271/178207). Atif Aziz himself commented on [this blog post](http://scottonwriting.net/sowblog/archive/2011/01/06/customizing-elmah-s-error-emails.aspx) the following information regarding this:

> If one does want a crack at the logged Error during mailing, one would
>   have to pick it up in the ErrorLogModule.Logged event. This could be
>   handy, for example, to push the Id of the logged error into the mail.
>   To do that, you'd stash away the Id from the Logged event into the
>   HttpContext and use it later in the Mailing event. For this to work,
>   the modules would have be registered such that the Mailing event
>   occurs after the Logged event.

I thought that since the httpModules are added with ErrorLog first and ErrorMail second, that this would achieve registering the Mailing event after the Logged event. I suppose that's talking about order of the events, not the order the Modules are applied in.

**How do you register the event order of HttpModules?**

I have tried the code below to no avail. The code below prevents the email from sending, but the error is still logged to the SQL table.

### Web.Config:

```
<system.web>
    <httpModules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" />
    </httpModules>
    <httpHandlers>
        <add verb="POST,GET,HEAD" path="elmah.axd" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
```

... and ...

```
<system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
    <modules>
        <add name="ErrorLog" type="Elmah.ErrorLogModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorMail" type="Elmah.ErrorMailModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
        <add name="ErrorFilter" type="Elmah.ErrorFilterModule, Elmah" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    </modules>
    <handlers>
        <add name="Elmah" path="elmah.axd" verb="POST,GET,HEAD" type="Elmah.ErrorLogPageFactory, Elmah" preCondition="integratedMode" />
    </handlers>
</system.webServer>
```

And of course the  and  are properly configured (I installed via NuGet).

### Global.asax.cs:

```
protected void ErrorLog_Logged(object sender, ErrorLoggedEventArgs args)
{
    Session["ElmahId"] = args.Entry.Id;
}

protected void ErrorMail_Mailing(object sender, ErrorMailEventArgs e)
{
    var elmahErrorId = Session["ElmahId"].ToString();
    e.Mail.Subject = String.Format("{0}, see ELMAH_Error.ErrorID = {1}", e.Mail.Subject, elmahErrorId);            
}
```

If I change the ErrorMail_Mailing event code in global.asax.cs to the following code, I receive the Email with the subject specified in the ErrorMail_Mailing event code as I should. I've even tried to just put Session.SessionID in the subject and that kills the email functionality. **This makes me think that the ErrorMail_Mailing event does not have Session access. Is this correct?**

```
protected void ErrorMail_Mailing(object sender, ErrorMailEventArgs e)
{
    e.Mail.Subject = "I changed the subject in global.asax";
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer was incredibly easy. The ErrorMailEventsArgs.Error object contains the session information at the time of exception. The ErrorMail_Mailing even does not have access to the session context. So, the solution is as simple as pulling your variable from the ErrorMailEventArgs.

```
protected void ErrorMail_Mailing(object sender, ErrorMailEventArgs e)
{
    var elmahErrorId = e.Error.SessionVariables["ElmahId"].ToString();
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(elmahErrorId))
        e.Mail.Subject = String.Format("{0}, see ELMAH_Error.ErrorID = {1}", e.Mail.Subject, elmahErrorId);
}
```

Also, simply by putting the ElmahId in Session in the ErrorLog_Logged event, if your ErrorMail handler is registered after ErrorLog (done by adding ErrorLog in web.config first), that session variable will be in the Session Variables section the standard ELMAH error email.

```
protected void ErrorLog_Logged(object sender, ErrorLoggedEventArgs args)
{
    Session["ElmahId"] = args.Entry.Id;
}
```

**Update:** Atif Aziz brought up that the Errors.SessionVariables is not in the original ELMAH source, but in a patch instead. Here is my packages.config:

```
<packages>
    <package id="elmah.corelibrary" version="1.2" />
    <package id="elmah" version="1.2.0.1" />
    <package id="elmah.sqlserver" version="1.2" />
</packages>
```

Comment: I would recommend using [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) instead of using [Session](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.session.aspx) to pass the logged error Id from the `Logged` and `Mailed` events.

Comment: Also, it looks like that you are using a patched version of ELMAH since the official version does not have any `SessionVariables` property off the `Error` class.

Comment: Interesting...I pulled a package from NuGet. Now I'd like to know which one, I kind of like that being there. Does the official ELMAH version write the session variables into the email it sends? I believe all installations we're using have been doing that, which I discovered simply by putting the entry ID in session it's in the email from that. My goal is having an easy way to get to the elmah.axd page from information provided by the email. In this case, the GUID elmah uses for the ErrorId in SQL can be used in query string to the elmah.axd handler to go straight to the details page.

Comment: What is the Id of the NuGet package you pulled? Check `packages.config` of your solution(s). There's only [one patch I am aware of by James Manning that adds support for specifically a collection called SessionVariables](http://blog.sublogic.com/2009/12/31/patch-to-enable-session-variable-logging-with-elmah/) but I don't believe that's up there on NuGet. In any event, it's better to use [HttpContext.Items](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.items.aspx) because that'll work irrespective of session state being enabled in a solution or not.

Comment: I added that in the answer above. Also, I can't seem to access HttpContext in the ErrorMail_Mailing event. It is null when that event fires. Is there something I have configured improperly?

Comment: `HttpContext` is the class. Its instance should be available off the [`Context`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.context.aspx) property of the application object in which your `ErrorMail_Mailing` event is located (assuming `Global.asax`). In other words, instead of `Session["ElmahId"]`, just use `Context.Items["ElmahId"]`.

Comment: Atif, thank you for all your patient help. Turns out, that despite looking at the settings a few times...in the MVC project I'm having problems in...the ErrorLog httpModule was added prior to the ErrorMail one. I was comparing 2 applications, one was right, the other not right. So, I suppose I missed that simple thing during comparison. Thanks again.

Comment: I am noticing one weird thing while trying to figure this out in debugger, but as this comment is getting long, I'll take it to the ELMAH discussions group at: http://groups.google.com/group/elmah/browse_thread/thread/5827acfef1799b4e