# How to use Elmah in Visual Studio non-ASP.Net library project

Tags: elmah

We need to use Elmah in a non-ASP.Net project.

In this library project, Elmah should log all uncaught exceptions and we should also be able to log or raise exceptions.

We have done this in web context but not in a library project. How can we achieve this or where can we find information about it?

Comment: See this previous answer for how to use Elmah in a non-asp.net library project. - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841451/using-elmah-in-a-console-application/1068378#1068378

Comment: Cool, you could post the link as an answer. Believe it or not, I searched for more than 2 hours :S....

Comment: Answers that are just links to other answers are automatically converted to comments. If this solves your problem, up-vote the original answer.

Comment: Alright! Had already done that. No worries and thanks!

Comment: You may be better off with Nlog in this case rather than Elmah. To me it seems more suited to non ASP.Net apps.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I ended up using Log4Net. Thanks!