# HttpTaskAsyncHandler and HTTP context

Tags: elmah, asp.net-4.5, httptaskasynchandler

I am just starting to learn how Task works, and get one interesting case.
I have **HttpTaskAsyncHandler** but I can't get acccess to HttpContext if my code inside  ProcessRequestAsync calls to some Task

```
  public class MyAsyncHandler : HttpTaskAsyncHandler, IReadOnlySessionState
    {
        public override async Task ProcessRequestAsync(HttpContext context)
        {
            //can use HttpContext here   
            await MyJob("data");
            //can use HttpContext here
        }

      public async Task MyJob(string data)
        {
            var func = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process(data));
            await func;
        }

        public string Process(string context)
        {
             **//can't use HttpContext here**
            Elmah.ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(ex);   
        }
}
```

is it possible to fix ? I understand that Process method would be call in other tread but anyway. 
Thanks/

Comment: Why are you pushing work to the thread pool and then `await`ing it? Why not just do the work on the request thread?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are correct that HttpContent does not exist inside of your Task, since it is in a separate thread. So you will need to access create a new instance of Elmah inside your Process method(new thread). You can follow the 2nd or 3rd answer in the previous question, [Using Elmah in a Console Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841451/using-elmah-in-a-console-application) to accomplish what you want.