# Error Logging for C#

Tags: c#, error-logging, error-reporting, sentry

I was previously using [Sentry](http://getsentry.com) for maintaining error logs on my C# application.
I want to switch to something that is downloadable since I have some sensitive data. Is there any error logging software like sentry but can be hosted by me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If you are already familiar with using sentry then you can install it on you own server: https://github.com/getsentry

Answer (score 1):

for C# use sentry client: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-csharp
also today I fix ssl problem for it: https://github.com/getsentry/raven-csharp/pull/52

Answer (score 0):

[Elmah (Error Logging Modules and Handlers)](https://code.google.com/p/elmah/) is good for this.

It is very easy to set up. There are various [Nuget packages](http://nuget.org/packages/elmah/) for different storage options. The most basic is to store the files in XML in the application's App_Data folder. Then you can configure access to the pretty web interface via the web.config.

Scott Hanselman has [an old but good write-up](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ELMAHErrorLoggingModulesAndHandlersForASPNETAndMVCToo.aspx) on it too.

Comment: Can Elmah be used for windows forms application?

Comment: I think you can with a bit of ingenuity. There's a discussion of various approaches [in answers to this other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/841451/using-elmah-in-a-console-application).