# How to log error in wpf application using Elmah

Tags: c#, wpf, elmah, error-logging

I have been implementing Desktop WPF application, and i want to implement Error logging functionality, so that it is useful to trace error in production environment.

As i have been using Elmah in my other web applications, i was thinking to use the same for Desktop WPF app.

I have tried the same configuration but its not working as of now.
Does Elmah not supported in Desktop WPF app??

Can anybody have exact idea and all configuration detail to set it up?
I would like to log Error in DB, which will be local sql server to client machine.

Comment: Why not try `log4Net`?

Comment: @NikhilAgrawal : Can you send me detail or step by step info for log4net?

Answer (score 0):

It seems possible. They use it here in a console app: [Using ELMAH in a console application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/841451/using-elmah-in-a-console-application)

May need some adapting but it's worth a try